# Application Failed to start The Dependencies of some of the Beans form a cycle... Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, endpoint

so I have this section of code in AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CurrentUserService currentUserService;
    private final SessionFilter sessionFilter;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    public AppConfig(CurrentUserService currentUserService, SessionFilter sessionFilter, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.currentUserService = currentUserService;
        this.sessionFilter = sessionFilter;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(currentUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http = http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                (request, response, authException) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
                }
        ).and();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(sessionFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

if I get rid of the @Lazy it will not start, i have tried to get rid of the constructor and do:

```
    @Autowired
    private final CurrentUserService currentUserService;
    @Autowired
    private final SessionFilter sessionFilter;
    @Autowired
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(currentUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

same thing, can someone please help me out, I really don't want to have to use the @Lazy Implementation. here is the error it returns:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\Blade\Documents\WebMent\modules\backend\build\classes\java\main\com\shortsdesigns\webment\configuration\AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

When getting rid of the constructor and using field injection it gives me this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Comment: Can you show the PasswordEncoder class?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html <- this is the password encoder Class I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you're creating the `PasswordEncoder` in the same class that you're injecting it.

The best solution is to not autowire the `PasswordEncoder` (or the `CurrentUserService`) at all.

It appears those instances are only used in the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method, which is redundant.

Registering a `PasswordEncoder` and `UserDetailsService` as a bean is enough for Spring Security to detect them and use them in your configuration.

In other words, you should remove the following code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(currentUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

The application will still behave in the exact same way.